# Java swing) I want to design pop up window based interface

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image]

This is the interface what I want to make.
The main frame includes 3 buttons which make pop-up new frames when they are clicked.

At first time. I planned to make 3 Jframe classes and then just call new instace of the classes on main class. But the problem is they have to manipulate same data in main class. (And I have to use synchronize method). It is hard to design it to me. please give me some advice.

Comment: You can always pass the objects from main to the other JFrames. Alternatively you can make sure the information will only be accessed through a singleton helper class

Comment: What have you tried? Also, don't use multiple `JFrame`sm you probably want `JDialog`s instead. Another option would be to make the main frame's buttons a menu and display the contents you want according to the selected option in the same frame.

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably make the popup frame classes inner classes within your main (controller) class

Comment: @user1803551 / I tried just make new frame instances added panel including buttons and textfields. But It had  a problem that they had same name component. So I couldn't handle the components...

Comment: I'm telling you not to make a new frame instances. Also, components with the same name is something you should just fix by changing the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend `JDialog` in a different class, create a new Layout and populate it with your components and then use the methode `add(yourpanel)`

In your `JFrame` create an instance of your custom `JDialog` and use it's method `.setVisible(true)`.

You can use the constructor from your class to pass in data.

Here is an example code :

```
public class Example extends JDialog{
public Example() {
    setResizable(false);
    setLocation(450, 40);
    setTitle("Example panel");
    JPanel bigPanel = new JPanel();

    String name = "test name"
    String email = "email";
    JLabel label = new JLabel(name);
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(email);
    bigPanel.add(label);
    bigPanel.add(label1);
    add(bigPanel);
    pack();
}
```

And for your JFrame class you just have to add action listeners for your buttons so when you click on them to instantiate your dialog.

Comment: 1) Don't set the location manually, it will be set by the OS and 2) by the location of the owner which you probably need to assign to it. 3) Class names start with an uppercase. 4) I suggest you test your answer before posting it because you will find it doesn't behave like you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it as you said.

Comment: It's a working solution, i've already tried it, and for that uppercase sorry it's an error that occured when i was changing my code here to post it to be readble for a newbie, and i added the location because, everyone would love to see the Dialog in the center of the screen, not randomly everywhere.

Comment: "*everyone would love to see the Dialog in the center of the screen, not randomly everywhere*" Which is exactly why you should not set your own location. Why do you think that `(450,50)` is the center for anyone? Also, tell me if both labels appear like you tried to.

Answer (score 0):

MDI (Multiple Document Interface) is one keyword of some interest.

What you have, is one **document** and several **editors** on it. The editors modify the document, and the document then tells all listeners (the editors) about the changes.

In swing you could use a StyledDocument for that. Start with some tutorials, like that of Alice in Wonderland.